# Check for winner in tic-tac-toe - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check all possible winner conditions in a tic-tac-toe game, how can I rewrite in a functional way?

```
board = numpy.array([[0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0]])
player = 1

if any([(board[0, :] == player).all(),
        (board[:, 0] == player).all(),
        (board[1, :] == player).all(),
        (board[:, 1] == player).all(),
        (board[2, :] == player).all(),
        (board[:, 2] == player).all()]):
    print('Win')
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for diagonal wins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the combination of `any` and `all` -

```
mask = board==player
out = mask.all(0).any() | mask.all(1).any()
```

To account for `diagonal` ones, bit more work -

```
out |= np.diag(mask).all() | np.diag(mask[:,::-1]).all()
```

Comment: Awesome... Also, for diagonals, you'd do `mask.diagonal().all()` and `mask[::-1].diagonal().all()` (if you want to account for those)